# Transparent official Twitter Widget

Tags: css, twitter, widget, background-color

I'd like to insert the official [Twitter Widget](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets) in a website.

So, I can't choose any background-color on this option page.
Is it possible to chance background-color from white to transparent?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
My solution was to alter the css of the twitter widget after the page is loaded using jQuery.

```
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("iframe.twitter-timeline")
             .contents()
             .find(".timeline")
             .css("background-color", "transparent");
    });
```

Downside of this is that until the page is loaded you get the white background so I placed the widget inside the container that is hidden and in the page load event after I replace the css I show the container.